# SVN upgrade marked all my files deleted

Tags: svn

Earlier I had svn version 1.6. I upgraded it to 1.8. When I tried to do svn up on my working copy, it said, `upgrade your working copy`. So I did upgrade my working copy. But when I did `svn st`, I saw all my files with status `D`. May be I incorrectly upgraded my working copy and all the metadata got erased. I haven't committed my changes yet. How do I restore my working copy?

1. I used `svn upgrade` to upgrade working copy
2. Now if I fire the above command, it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try `svn cleanup`. If that did not help, I would then do `svn revert -R`. Failing that as well, I would just delete the working copy and start over with a new checkout.